# Need help to write bat file that execute sql scripts in (sql server 2008 and another 3 files.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I am sure these has been asked before but cannot find clear instruction how to create a 
batch file lets call it "Update Database" this batch file should

Execute sql scripts located in  different folders
Execute another 3 bat files.

Any quick examples how to do it?Never done it before
thanks a lot

## EDITED

Can I do this?

```
:On Error exit 

:r C:\myPath\MasterUpdateDatabase.bat
GO 
SQLCMD -S (Local) -i C:\myPath\InsertUsername.sql
```

I get an error:

> "GO" is not recognized as internal external command

Thanks for any input

Comment: You're telling us what you executed, and the error, but not **how you executed it**.

Comment: It looks like you're treating the batch script like a SQL Query.  The syntax is quite different.  The ":r" is your function, which only calls the batch file.  The "GO" is unnecessary.  There is likely a cleaner way for you to create some error handling and multiple commands being called.  From the batch file call, you'd probably want to use "START /WAIT" so that your original batch file doesn't finish before the one you've called from within it.  Are you able to post additional details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use DOS commands to create a batch file that either (a) executes other batch files or (b) executes SQLCMD to run sql or a sql script.

Here are a couple examples all rolled into one.  I'm using the DOS command `START` with the `/WAIT` switch, which will keep your original "master" batch file running in one window and execute the subsequent file or commands in a new window.  That new window stays open until the script finished AND exits.

Some of the `ECHO`s probably aren't required, but the script will talk back to you for now, a little.

```
@echo off
```

So, this is pretty simple in the sense that you're just running the script.  If you're script1.bat has break points, you can return an error back to the main script and have it end immediately.  I wasn't clear if that was what you needed the master script to do.

```
echo Starting Database Update.
echo.

echo Excuting Script 1
echo.
start /wait C:\path\to\your\script1.bat

echo If there was a problem, break here.
Pause

echo Excuting Script 2
echo.
start /wait C:\path\to\your\script2.bat

echo If there was a problem, break here.
Pause
```

Here is where did used the same START /WAIT to run SQLCMD, which in this case just returns results from the query.  One thing to note here is that the `-Q` (uppercase) runs the query and quits.  If you use `-q` (lowercase) it will run the query and sit open in SQLCMD waiting for another query.

```
echo.
echo Running SQLCMD: "select top 100 * from sys.objects"
start /wait sqlcmd -S (local) -Q "select top 100 * from sys.objects"
```

And this is how you can run a sql script, which is what the `-i` denotes, but I also didn't run this in the START /WAIT as earlier.  Not that you have to, but I wanted to show both examples.  What this also shows is the `-b` will end the batch process if your script returns an error, which is useful if you're running multiple scripts that depend on success of the former(s).

```
echo.
echo Running SQLCMD from an (-i)nput file:
sqlcmd -S (local) -i  C:\path\to\your\script.sql -b

echo.
echo Update Complete.
pause

End
```

So, I assumed you were looking for a .bat or .cmd file that utilized SQLCMD.  The example I provided is pretty basic, but hopefully it sets you on the right path.

OH!  And remember that CTRL+C breaks a batch script in process.

Answer (score 1):

The actual error you're seeing is that the command line interpreter does not recognize 'GO', so you could just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you :

```
sqlplus UserName/Password@DataBase @C:\myPath\InsertUsername.sql
```

P.S : Don't forget to add the command "commit;" at the end of sql file (InsertUsername.sql), this command order Oracle to save performed changes in darabase

Answer (score -1):

This answer definitely works for your purposes:

`sqlcmd -S localhost -U fdmsusr -P fdmsamho  -i "E:\brantst\BranchAtt.sql" -o "E:\brantst\branchlog.txt"`

Comment: What in your answer is different from what the questioner already tried?

Comment: you'd rather explain why your answer would solve his problem