# MS SQL Server work on schedule without using Agent?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Every day and month i do same things which update and insert data on specific tables. 
the problem is that i m unable to use Agent for using scheduler Cuz of 'sa ' right. In this case, is there any other options exisited in ms sql? or
Is it possible to link vb and sql for solving this problem ?
plz  comment any ideas and how will work 
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use windows scheduler. Create a scheduled task and run your queries either via sqlcmd or for example create a powershell script

Sqlcmd is probably easier, here is some info
[Executing a stored procedure using Windows task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321023/executing-a-stored-procedure-using-windows-task-scheduler)
you can also save your script into a file and run it via sqlcmd using [-i inputfile] command line argument