# Create jobs in SQL Server Express edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, batch-file, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 (Express Edition).
I want to create a job which will delete all data from the all the table(>50) in the DB everyday at night 1:00.
Instead of Deleteting i decide to restore the DB from the Script.

It would have been easy by using SQL Server Agent, But this is limitation in SQL Server Express.

I figured out that  we can create jobs "manually" by creating batch files and SQL script files, and running them via Windows Task Scheduler.

I have no clue what i have to write in bat file and sql file.This is my first time where i am working so deeply in SQL configuration. Can someone help please?

Name of the script which i need to restore is test.sql.

If any one has different approach , please share.

Thanks
Prat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing a stored procedure using Windows task Scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321023/executing-a-stored-procedure-using-windows-task-scheduler)

Comment: First write code, check with `sqlcmd.exe` and if it works, schedule it with Task Scheduler. Another way is to use PowerShell, create scheduled task and use SMO to interact with database

Comment: Why is this tagged for MySQL?

Comment: @RichardSt-Cyr http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/304143/can-we-stop-suggesting-both-sql-server-and-mysql-in-the-suggested-tags

Comment: @lad2025: Thanks for the info

Comment: @lad2025 : I am sure my question is duplicate one. I am trying to figure out the answer which will help me to understand things very easily. I dont have time to read lot of thing for the moment. This is my first and last time i am going to do this job. With the help of the answer posted by you experts helped me to know lot of things. Tat is why i conclude that i have to write batch and sql to make this job. But i dont know what exactly i have to write in that file. If you can please help.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch files needs to look like this. Change the path to your .sql file and also put in the sql server info. You can read more about sqlcmd [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). Also note the case on the switches `-S and -i` as it does matter.

```
sqlcmd -S <ComputerName>\<InstanceName> -i C:\test.sql
```