# Auto update sql server database in every second interval

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, timer, scheduled-tasks

I am developing an asp.net application that will require auto-update sql server database table records every second. After 45 seconds i need to reset the values and restart the same process.

I know about sql server job scheduler but I can't use it as i am using sql server express. I can also use windows services, but it will require to manage separately other then asp.net application.

So what will be the best way to auto update sql server db in every second interval?
I also have to display records every second for which i am using [jquery datatable auto reload](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) feature-

Comment: Why dont you make a hitcounter if your "jquery datatable auto reload" that fires each second hits 45 clear your database?

Comment: I think you could use window task scheduler to achieve it. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321023/executing-a-stored-procedure-using-windows-task-scheduler

Comment: @RandRandom, How can I auto update database in every one second? I am looking for a better way to develop timer so that its not required to manage separately from asp.net application.

Comment: @yadavr I dont really know I just quoted what you are saying for me it sounded like you already have a function that auto reloeds every second so I thought if you already have something that ticks every second why dont Count them and when it hits 45 do something else. Just my 2 Cents.

Comment: @RandRandom, that is for displaying data on html page and it works fine, but to update database in every one second, it can't be achieve from this because its independent from web request.